# In SAS how to print leading and lagging observations

Tags: sas

I am looking for a way to print the current, leading and lagging observation according to a flag variable. If an observation is flagged, I want to print that observation, plus its lagging and leading row.

Have:

```
    ID        VAR1        VAR2        Flag
    --------------------------------------      
    ID1        1           15           .
    ID1        2           14           1
    ID1        3           13           .
    ID1        4           12           .
    ID2        5           11           .
    ID2        6           10           .
    ID2        7            9           1
    ID2        8            8           .   
    ID2        9            7           . 
    ID3        10           6           .
    ID3        11           5           1
    ID3        12           4           .
    ID3        13           3           .
    ID3        14           2           1
    ID3        15           1           .
```

Want:

```
    ID        VAR1        VAR2        Flag
    --------------------------------------      
    ID1        1           15           .
    ID1        2           14           1
    ID1        3           13           .
    ID2        6           10           .
    ID2        7            9           1
    ID2        8            8           .  
    ID3        10           6           .
    ID3        11           5           1
    ID3        12           4           .
    ID3        13           3           .
    ID3        14           2           1
    ID3        15           1           .
```

I have tried the `Proc Expand` functions, but since this procedure cannot deal with missing values, it is not appropriate in my working case.

Another approach is to order the dataset to the desired order and then create a variable numbering each row in order--printing current row +1,-1 on condition of the flag.

Is there a more direct way of achieving a dataset consisting of current, lagging and leading rows according to a flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the previous value of FLAG is easy to do with the LAG() function. Finding the next value is a little harder.  Here is a method.

```
data want ;
  set have end=eof;
  by id ;
  if not eof then set have(keep=flag rename=(flag=lead_flag) firstobs=2);
  lag_flag=lag(flag);
  if first.id then call missing(lag_flag);
  if last.id then call missing(lead_flag);
  if flag or lead_flag or lag_flag ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use var1+1 and var-1 for flag = . as shown below.

```
     proc sql;
create table want as 
select distinct a.* from 
(select * from have)a
inner join 
(select * from have
where flag = 1 )b
on a.var1 = b.var1
or a.var1 = b.var1-1
or a.var1 = b.var1 +1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general scenario would be

- Within each group report each row meeting a fulcral condition as well as *p* rows before and *q* rows after

*p* and *q* would correspond to the concepts of *lag-size* and *lead-size*. A hash object can track a within group sequence number for the rows that should be output.  The double DOW technique is used to measure over the group (compute the seq number for output) and then evaluate the measure for each item in the group.

For example:

```
data have;
  do id = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D';
    do seq = 1 to 36;
       rowid + 1;

       x = seq;
       if id = 'D' then x = floor(12*ranuni(123));

       flag = mod(x,7);
       output;
    end;
  end;
run;


%let lagsize = 2;
%let leadsize = 3;

data want;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash marks();
    retain __n .;
    marks.defineKey('__n');
    marks.defineData('__n');
    marks.defineDone();
  end;

  marks.clear();
  do __n = 1 by 1 until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if 
      flag=0 /* fulcrum criteria checked for each row in group */
    then do;
      * computation is "store sequence number that would fall in the lag lead 'about' space";
      _n_ = __n;
      do __n = _n_ - &lagsize to _n_ + &leadsize;
        marks.replace();
      end;
      __n = _n_;
    end;
  end;

  do __n = 1 to __n;
    set have;
    if marks.check()=0 then output; * evaluate for each row in group;
  end;
run;
```

The technique can be extended to the case of wanting different 'about' sizes based on different fulcral conditions.